# ASP.NET Core 2 + Angular -> how set up VSTS?

Tags: asp.net, angular, azure, continuous-integration, azure-devops

I have my **ASP.NET Core + Angular WebApp** uploaded to GitHub(through VSTS) and now I would like to set up the CI pipeline. After that I would like to **deploy** my app **to Azure**.


In the template section - there is an **ASP.NET Core template**, but also an **Azure Web App template**.


**Considering my case which is better suited for this case?**

Comment: Do you have one single project which contains both? Or are they separated in a dedicated API and SPA Project which will provide separated outputs?

Comment: @ChrisRichner it's one solution and one ASP.NET Core project. There is a folder within that project named ClientApp that contains all (I believe) Angular stuff. The project is basically the new Angular template that came out just a few days ago with ASP.NET Core 2.0.0  BTW you can check it out and take a look at it in ...like 30 seconds...if you have .Core 2 installed on your machine :)

Comment: _dotnet new angular_ rules! ,)

Comment: FYI Did you already know how easy it is nowadays to go from code to running site. Check out _Create a .NET Core web app in a Linux container in Azure | Microsoft Docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/quickstart-dotnetcore?WT.mc_id=docs-twitter_

Comment: Do you solve this issue with my solution?

Comment: @starain-MSFT not yet, I need more information. check my comments below, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the **almost** perfect working answer in [Levi Fuller's blog](https://medium.com/@levifuller/how-to-deploy-an-angular-cli-application-built-on-asp-net-1fa03c0ca365).
You can get it working with a minor change: unlike what Levi states, you really need **only a single** npm task

1. set up the **npm task**

   - by clicking the three dots button -> set the **Working folder with package.json** to your folder that contains the package.json file.

2. set up the **Azure App Service Deploy**

   - by clicking the three dots button -> set the **Package or folder** to your folder that contains the .csproj file.

[image: build definition]

Answer (score 0):

There isn’t the build template that you use directly, the template is convenient to use, you need to modify it per to detail requirement.

Refer to these steps:

1. Go to build page of team project (e.g. `https://XXX.visualstudio.com/[teamproject]/_build`)
2. Click +New button to create a build definition with ASP.NET Core template

[image]

[image]

3. Add npm install task before .NET Core Restore task (Command: `install`; Working folder with package.json:[package.json folder path])

[image]

4. (optional) Delete/disable .NET Core Test task if you don’t need
5. Add Azure App Service Deploy task at the end (Package or folder: `$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)/**/*.zip`; Check `Publish using Web Deploy` option)

[image]

Note: you can move step 4 to release and link this build to release (change package or folder to `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/*.zip`).

Comment: oh, I will need a muuuch more detailed answer than this, buddy.

Comment: @PaxForce I add the screenshots.

Comment: I tried it today morning (sorry I couldn't get to it sooner). After step 2. (after I click the +New button), it requires me to fill out 'Agent queue', which is a mandatory field. Could you please tell me what to write into that field? Thank you.

Comment: also, what is the Working folder with package.json path? Can you give an example?

Comment: @PaxForce 1. You can choose 'Hosted VS2017' agent. 2. You can click ... button to select the path of package.json (By default, it is in the project folder). You also can use [predefined variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/definitions/build/variables?tabs=batch), such as $(Build.SourcesDirector)\MyCoreWithAngular (1. Click Get Source 2. Change the server path to your core solution folder (click ..., local path can be empty, MyCoreWithAngular is the  project folder)

Comment: @PaxForce What's the result now? Do you solve this issue?

Comment: I was kinda busy, but I will check it out at the weekend and I'll report back to you.

Comment: @PaxForce What's the result now?

Comment: could I contact you via Skype, please?

Comment: You can open a new thread for the issue of no package found with specified pattern.