# Azure Dev OPs Pipeline for Angular Visual studio Template

Tags: azure, visual-studio, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Ive built an app using this template.
[image: Angular template]

This is the project structure:

[image]

The angular app is in the folder ClientApp

Id like help wioth a Azure Dev OPs pipeline for UAT and Production to:

1. build the angluar app and .net app,
2. run the tests for both angular and .net
3. deploy to azure
4. run db code first migrations

Any help or resources would be great, im surprised there not a template yaml file for this already tbh.

I thought this being the built in template shipped with visual studio there would be more resources for it but I cant really find anything useful

Ive already tried following this https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5286555/Setting-Up-a-Build-and-Release-Pipeline-for-ASP-NE but kept having failures on the restore step and i dont think its very clear either

Thank you

Comment: If your question is closed, don't just repost it. It will simply be closed again. Review the Stack Overflow help center and learn how to rewrite your question to be answerable.

Comment: I have added a bit more info, it did suggest reposting it. How can i make my questions clearer?

Comment: Well, for starters, your problem right now is "I'm having an issue restoring packages." Focus on that question. What do the logs say? What does your pipeline look like? Pretend like a colleague is asking you for help troubleshooting the problem. What information would you want to look at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure that your project can be built and tested fine locally, and then [connect it to Azure DevOps service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/projects/connect-to-projects?view=azure-devops&tabs=visual-studio-2019#connect-from-visual-studio-or-team-explorer), so push this local repository to Azure Repos.

Following this doc: [Continuous integration and deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/azure/devops/cicd?view=aspnetcore-5.0#configure-the-azure-pipelines-pipeline) to configure the Azure pipeline. You need the `npm task` to install the dependencies before `dotnet restore` step.
[image]

See: [ASP.NET Core 2 + Angular -> how set up VSTS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46509883/asp-net-core-2-angular-how-set-up-vsts) and [Create a build pipeline for Angular and ASP.NET Core apps with Visual Studio Team Services](https://dotnetthoughts.net/create-a-build-pipeline-for-aspnetcore-angular-with-vsts/) for more guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Try to verify my YAML file

https://github.com/felipementel/AzureDevOps-YAML/blob/main/src/dotnetCore_Angular-AppService.yaml

after configuring your Azure DevOps Pipeline with YAML file, you still need to change the Physical Path in your App Service.
Check the image bellow

[image]